# Hbase scan showing hexa character for special character

Tags: hive, hbase

Inserted data to hbase table through hive external table.
Hive table contains basically 3 columns

- id - String
- identifier -  map<string,string>
- src - string

inserted the tale to hbase table.
map data present in hive table for identifier  column.
sample map data

```
 {"CUSTID":"CUST4302109","LYLT":"44302109"}
```

Data inserted to hbase table. while fetching the data through scan command.

```
O2008031353044301300                       column=INTR:IDNFS-string, timestamp=1626515550906, value=CUSTID\x03CUST4301300\x02\x03\x02LYLT\x0344301300
```

Hexachar are coming instead of special char.

Using below mentioned properties, while creating the hbase hive external table,

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe'
STORED BY
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'`enter code here`
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'hbase.columns.mapping'=':key,INTR:CID,INTR:IDNFS-string,INTR:SRC',enter code here
  'hbase.table.default.storage.type' ='string',
  'serialization.format'='1')
```

how to get the actual special char?

Comment: does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725645/hbase-shell-scan-bytes-to-string-conversion

Comment: Thanks @hatefAlipoor this link help a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HBase shell scan bytes to string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725645/hbase-shell-scan-bytes-to-string-conversion)